# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, aws-sdk-net

I am getting this error after upgrading the AWSSDK.S3(3.7.107) for dot net core version 6.0.
The same code is working fine using AWSSDK.S3(3.5.0.4) for dot net core 3.1.

```
            var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
            {
                BucketName = "bucket-name-mobile/test",
                Key = "637431660687617131_Sachin_Pakale.jpg",
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
            };

            url = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
```

Found that the later version is encoding my URL by replaceing forward slash with %2F making it invalid.

```
<StringToSign>GET 1688208529 /bucket-name-mobile%2Ftest/637431660687617131_Sachin_Pakale.jpg</StringToSign>
```

My bucket name has forward slashes being the nested folder structure.
Is there any workaround or provision to avoid this encoding? I am using USEast1 region.

Comment: Did you try placing the subfolder in the key property ? (BucketName = "bucket-name-mobile", Key = "test/637431660687617131_Sachin_Pakale.jpg") (cf : https://lightrun.com/answers/aws-aws-sdk-java-v2-s3-bucket-name-containing-slash-character-fails-with-any-operation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bucket name can't contain slashes. If your bucket contains "the folder" called *test*, then you need to modify your key parameter:

```
var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
{
    BucketName = "bucket-name-mobile",
    Key = "test/637431660687617131_Sachin_Pakale.jpg",
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
};

url = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
```